# CSS - Select area of an image and display

Tags: css, css-sprites

I need help creating images for my navigation menu.
I saw a site that has only one image that includes lots of small images and I guess the site recognises which to use and where and when.

For example: [show image](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/141116/4example_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg)

How can I select the home button, the settings button, and the star button and use them separately?

Thanks

Comment: This question is CSS and the concept you are looking for is called: sprite.

Comment: maybe http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Oh. I did not know this is CSS stuff. Then sorry for posting a thread in php, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a PHP related question. Actually, it's about CSS. As mentioned above, the concept you're looking for is called 'Sprite'. Here is an example based on the link you provided:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#home {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: url(http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141116/4example_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg) 0 0;
}

#next {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: url(http://kepfeltoltes.hu/141116/4example_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg) -115px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="home" src=""><br><br>
<img id="next" src="">

</body>
</html>
```